# My Careers 2.0 account is not linked to my Stack Overflow account

Tags: support, jobs, stack-exchange

I recently got invited to Careers 2.0, and created my profile there. Soon after I looked over at the stack exchange website and tried to create accounts on all of the sites that I'm interested. Well done, I've created all of them, but now I can't link my Careers 2.0 and Stack Overflow accounts, despite the fact that I'm using the same Stack Exchange OpenID on both of them.

Is it possible to somehow add my Careers 2.0 account to the Stack Overflow that is linked to my Stack Exchange one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well my Careers 2.0 account is certainly linked to my Stack Overflow account, as well as to whatever Stack Exchange accounts I wanted to link it to.

- The way I do it is as follows: at Careers / edit profile, I go to Stack Exchange section -> *Stack Exchange Accounts* and click *edit*. This opens a list of my SE accounts. Then, I choose the ones I would want to show at Careers and click *save*:

  > [image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/6bjCg.jpg]

Comment: That's it! Just after I entered the network sites they didn't appeared on this list, what made me think that the accounts where not linked, but now I looked again at it and the sites appeared! Thank you!

Comment: @LiordinoNeto you're welcome. By the way you can also take a look at an "instruction" explaining how we at Stack Exchange deal with _helpful_ answers: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235

Comment: Thanks for sharing this info, @gnat!

Answer (score 1):

If you are referring to show the link to your Careers account on the list of your [accounts](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1262628/liordino-neto?tab=accounts), by design that is not show in that list.
That list reports your account's links to Stack Exchange sites where you can gain reputation. Careers is not a Q&A site, and the link to your Careers' account is not shown anywhere in your profile page.

You can add the link in the "About Me" section of your profile.

[image: screenshot]