# Unable to link SE accounts from Careers profile (but can link to SO answers)

Tags: support, jobs

I've come across posts regarding this same issue - all of which seemed to be resolved by Careers support - but even after contacting support, this is still an issue for me.

On my Careers profile, I can see the "Stack Exchange" section just fine (and can even link to answers from my Stack Overflow account), along with an "edit" button. However when the edit button is clicked, I see an empty space where I would expect to see a list of my Stack Exchange profiles:

[image]

It allows me to click "Save" and after doing so, I see this:

[image]

Any help with this would be most appreciated.

Comment: did you do it as shown [at screen shot in this answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125296/165773)? **1) Careers / edit profile, 2) go to Stack Exchange section -> Stack Exchange Accounts and 3) click edit to open a list of SE accounts. 4) choose the ones you would want to show at Careers and 5) click save**

Comment: @gnat: Yep, I followed those exact steps with the results posted above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed.  Sorry about that!

Comment: It has indeed been fixed. Thanks so much, David (and the rest of the SO Careers crew)!

Comment: Just wanted to let you know this particular error is appearing again on my end (May 25th, 2012). Same exact description as above.

Comment: @Jordan try it now?

Comment: @DavidFullerton works perfectly. Thanks. What was the issue, just curious?

Comment: @Jordan ...we actually have no idea and are still trying to track it down.  I had to manually hit the "re-sync" button

Comment: I have the same issue! how did you solve it?

Comment: Hello. I'm having the same problem. I created some new accounts using the same OpenID (Google) after the careers account creation, but the new accounts don't appear in my careers profile. Thanks!

Comment: Same problem for me too :(

Comment: @KeesCook your accounts are there now.  Thanks for the report, it turns out we were not firing off an account sync when you create your account, it was just being handled by the natural queue (which processes all users every 12 hours or so).  Everything should be up to date now.