# Unable to link SE accounts on Stack Careers

Tags: bug, jobs, linked-accounts

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Unable to link SE accounts from Careers profile (but can link to SO answers)](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129492/unable-to-link-se-accounts-from-careers-profile-but-can-link-to-so-answers)

Seeing the following when I try to select an account (200+ rep) to link to my account. [image]

Comment: Did you use different email addresses to login to Stack Exchange versus Careers?

Comment: @animuson it was fixed in the comments here: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129492/unable-to-link-se-accounts-from-careers-profile-but-can-link-to-so-answers/130462#comment371157_130462