# Unable to add top answers from some SE sites to Careers 2.0 profile

Tags: bug, status-completed, answers, jobs, beta-sites

I was recently invited to create a Careers 2.0 account, and I find myself experiencing the *opposite* of [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129492/unable-to-link-se-accounts-from-careers-profile-but-can-link-to-so-answers): I can link my top Stack Exchange accounts to my Careers profile just fine, but when I try to add top answers from some of those accounts, it says "**Sorry, you don't seem to have any answers on that site. Choose another.**"

The issue seems to affect (mostly?) beta SE sites, but not all beta sites are affected.  Specifically, some of the sites where this happens (with links to my profile there) include:

- [Code Golf (beta)](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/3191)
- [Cryptography (beta)](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/598)
- [Biology (beta)](https://biology.stackexchange.com/users/239)
- [Travel (beta)](https://travel.stackexchange.com/users/952)
- [The Great Outdoors (beta)](https://outdoors.stackexchange.com/users/382)

On the other hand, some beta sites are apparently *not* affected, including:

- [Graphic Design (beta)](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/users/3239)
- [Board and Card Games (beta)](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/users/2203)

All the non-beta sites I've tried seem to be unaffected.

Pasting a link to one of my answers from those sites into the input box *does* work, or at least it did when I just tested it.  However, I'm pretty sure that, when I tried it yesterday, it *didn't* work, but just said "**The link you provided doesn't lead to a stackexchange answer by you. Please try again.**" even thought the links clearly did work in my browser.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bug only happened in the case when you have an account on more than 30 of our network sites, and only when you tried to add a question from a site you created your 31th+ account on.  The new code loops through all of your site users now.  Hopefully this didn't affect too many people :)

I appreciate your patience on this fix, which is going out now.