# How to add linked accounts to careers profile

Tags: support, status-completed, jobs

I can't seem to add linked accounts to my career 2.0 profile. I click on edit and it tells me to select my linked accounts, but there is nothing listed.

[image]

Comment: How many accounts do you have?

Comment: hm well, with [over 2K rep at SO](http://stackoverflow.com/users/442695/), you definitely should be able to add an account the same way as I do it ([explained here, with screen shot and step-by-step instructions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/125296/165773))

Comment: @gdoron I have 3 or 4

Comment: @gnat I did that, however nothing shows in my list as seen in my screenshot

Comment: @Bot I see - this looks like a bug; hope developers will fix it

Comment: @Bot. Why do you have _"3 or 4"_ accounts?

Comment: @gdoron because I have accounts on meta, stack, area51 etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed this last night. Thanks for the report.

Comment: Seems to be fixed now. Thanks